# Prevent repeated queries in Apollo Server 2

Tags: security, graphql, apollo-server

For security reasons, I am looking for a way to block bad actors from sending repeated queries on the server over and over again, as it may result in a poor execution performance and/or high deployment price.

In the [Apollo Server Documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/features/data-sources.html#Using-Memcached-Redis-as-a-cache-storage-backend), there is a link to how to implement our own cache backend using `KeyValueCache`, but I am just not sure about how to use it to prevent repeated queries from running multiple times.

Maybe I am not viewing the whole matter from the right angle, so please if you have any suggestions it would be of a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to implement some kind of rate-limiting middleware. A simple example using [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
const app = express()

const limitMiddleware = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 100,
})

app.use(limitMiddleware)
server.applyMiddleware({ app })

app.listen({ port: 4000 })
```

By default, the middleware keys off the request IP, but if you wanted to get more granular and key off both the IP and the query field name (for example), you could parse the request body using `graphql-tag` and generate a key accordingly.

GraphQL presents some unique challenges around security. You can take a look at [this article](https://blog.apollographql.com/securing-your-graphql-api-from-malicious-queries-16130a324a6b) for a more in-depth discussion, but in addition to rate limiting, you may also want to look into the following measures:

1. Amount limiting - using limits at the storage level, using custom scalars or implementing checks inside resolvers to prevent returning too many of one "thing" at a time
2. Query depth limiting - `graphql-depth-limit`
3. Limiting general query complexity and cost - `graphql-validation-complexity` and `graphql-cost-analysis`

While these tools don't necessarily address the scenario in your question, I would still consider using some combination of them as you dive into figuring out how to secure your endpoint.

Comment: I used the key `req.ip + gql'${req.body.query}'` and it worked fine. Thank you for your detailed answer and your other suggestions